# Cloning form elements on click is duplicating the data

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to duplicate a form with it's fields on click of an anchor tag.  The reason that it's not behaving correctly is because the jQuery click event is bound inside of a `$('body').on('click')` event (that has to be there, by the way, for other code that I have to work.  Also what's strange is that if you enter a value into one of the text fields and click 'clone' it produces a random amount of extra elements.  Any clues as to what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

Example of the issue can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/MJrUF/1/

Comment: You are binding a new event on each body click to the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding an addition click handler to existing `add-btn` on each `body` click. Probably you need something like below which uses delegation so don't have to worry about new button carrying the clone functionality.

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-btn', function (e) {
    // Other necessary code unrelated to this form is here

    e.preventDefault();
    var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.form-wrapper');
    var data = $wrapper.clone(true);
    $wrapper.after(data);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MJrUF/2/

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Lesson learned: don't try and bind new events when events are bound to the body already.  I just had to re-create the body event in its own closure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying something with a different approach, such as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrW3h/

```
    $("button.clone").live("click", function(){
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
            .appendTo("body")
            .attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex)
            .find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 3) {
                    this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                }
        });
        cloneIndex++;
    });
```